# need reference for documentation on ternary operator using push

Tags: javascript, push, ternary

I have the following:

```
let currentLocalStorage = [];
currentLocalStorage = (initialLoad) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks')): (currentLocalStorage.push(taskInput.value),currentLocalStorage)
```

which works but I would like to get a reference or documentation for the following:

```
: (currentLocalStorage.push(taskInput.value),currentLocalStorage)
```

so basically we are pushing on to the array and then defaulting to the array.  I was surprised that we can do this and was wondering where one we look for the documentation

Comment: No it doesn't, it only seems like it works. `JSON.parse` will throw instead of fail when it's given bad data, so: never put it in a ternary, just write normal code. Especially given the silliness in the second part of the ternary. The language permits this, but don't write code like this.

Comment: Case of a confusing  one liner that is actually longer than writing it out with a simpler to read if() :: 



   `let currentLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks') || '[]');
    if ( initialLoad ) {   currentLocalStorage.push(taskInput.value)   }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). Because `.push()` returns the new length of the array, you want to make sure you don't assign that to `currentLocalStorage`, so you use the comma operator to have that expression evaluate to `currentLocalStorage`.

So it effectively becomes `currentLocalStorage = currentLocalStorage` in that case, except now the array has one more item thanks to `.push()`.